# Notifying objects about an event

Tags: java, events, propertychangelistener

I'm looking for an effective method to trigger a change in a set of objects after a change was done to the key object. What I want to do is this:
There is one object that if changed executes a method in other objects.

I was trying to use PropertyChangeListener to accomplish this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BoundSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PropertyChangeListener Sample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JButton button1 = new JButton("Open");
        final JButton button2 = new JButton("Cancel");

        final String[] languages = { "English", "Spanish" };

        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(languages);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();


        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JComboBox comboTmp = (JComboBox) actionEvent.getSource();

                if (combo.getSelectedItem().equals("English") || combo.getSelectedItem().equals("Ingles")) {
                    String[] langs = { "English", "Spanish" };
                    comboTmp.setModel(new JComboBox(langs).getModel());
                }
                else if (combo.getSelectedItem().equals("Spanish") || combo.getSelectedItem().equals("Espanol")) {
                    String[] langs = { "Ingles", "Espanol" };
                    comboTmp.setModel(new JComboBox(langs).getModel());
                }
            }
        };

        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent) {
                String property = propertyChangeEvent.getPropertyName();

                JComboBox comboTmp = (JComboBox) propertyChangeEvent.getSource();
                String language = (String) comboTmp.getItemAt(0);

                System.out.println(language);

                if ("model".equals(property)) {
                    if (language.equals("English")) {
                        button1.setLabel("Open");
                        button2.setLabel("Cancel");
                    } else if (language.equals("Ingles")) {
                        button1.setLabel("Abierto");
                        button2.setLabel("Cancelar");
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        combo.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        combo.addActionListener(actionListener);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        panel.add(button1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        contentPane.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that with the growing number of objects the propertyChange() method will expend and it will become difficult to manage. Moreover to add a new JComponent I will also have to modify propertyChange().

Is there a way to do it the other way around by making the objects "look" for a change in the key object and cause them to act accordingly instead of acting upon them by performing the action in the PropertyChangeListener of the key object? Or maybe other neat way to do this?

Comment: there are binding frameworks which take over the boilerplate wiring, f.i. BetterBeansBinding or JGoodies Binding

Answer (score 3):

First off, a recommendation - always get a native speaker to do your translations.  It helps to avoid certain types of errors.  For instance, the word you've chosen as the replacement for 'open' is usually used as an adjective (as in, 'an open window') not as a verb, while you're using the inifinitive tense for 'cancel'.  You also don't have accent marks, which may be confusing to some readers (some words are only different because of their accent marks...).

Next, you shouldn't hard-code language choices or uses; they should be loaded from `.properties` files or similar.  This makes maintanence trivial, especially when adding *additional* languages.  @Mort's answer about using the observer pattern is correct - that is how updates should be handled.  Here's (really roughly) how to deal with the language aspects:
First, you need some `.properties` files.

```
spanishButtonNames.properties
==================================
openButton=Abrir
cancelButton=Cancelar

englishButtonNames.properties
==================================
opernButton=Open
cancelButton=Cancel
```

You'll want to wrap these up in some sort of `PropertyManager` that'll deal with loading the resource files behind the scenes, when the language is asked for (and possibly deallocating resources).

Next, when creating your buttons, name them:

```
JButton openButton = new JButton();
openButton.setName("openButton");
// And add them to a list
buttonList.add(openButton);
// More buttons....
```

Updating the buttons off of the button list is then trivial.  You can have just the `buttonList` listen for (and propogate) updates:

```
for(JButton button : buttonList) {
    button.setText(languagePropertyManager.getProperty(button.getName()));
}
```

(Note that with some clever coding, it's possible to load even the GUI layout from a text file, but I've never tried that.  I believe there are frameworks to handle that, however.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)? It does what you want: objects will register at an object to get notified when something happens.

[observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)